# Recursive Relations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recursive-algorithms

I've been doing recursive relations and found a question I wasn't able to solve. I'm given a recursive algorithm that finds the $\gcd$ of two numbers $p$ and $q$.

Algorithm:

```
function GCD(p,q)
    if (q == 0) then
        return p;
    else
        return GCD(q, p mod q)
```

Now in the question they have stated that the worst case input of this algorithm would be  $p = fib(n)$  ,  $q = fib(n-1)$. And then we have to analyze the running time complexity of this algorithm.

Now I know how to compute the running time of recursive algorithms but I don't know how to break this GCD ($p$ , $p$ mod $q$).

I tried to calculate.

If $p = fib(n)$ and $q = fib(n-1)$ -> GCD $(fib (n-1), fib (n-2))$ but then this keeps doing on and on. How can I break this down?

Comment: Also I wanted to know how is this the worst case input?

Answer (score 1):

You are counting down the Fibonacci numbers, which will end when you get to zero.  If $p=fib(n)$, it will take $n$ trips through your algorithm.  [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) lets you compute $n$ from $fib(n)$

Comment: Can we do it without Binet's formula?

Comment: You can ignore the $\psi^n$ in Binet's formula-it goes rapidly to zero.  Then $F_n \approx \frac {\varphi^n}{\sqrt 5},$ so $n\approx \frac{\log (\sqrt 5F_n)}{\log \varphi}$ and round to the nearest whole number, which will be very close if $n$ is at all large